# How do I make a UIView clickable in MonoTouch?

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm currently trying to create a simple UIView which contains some labels and images.
How can I set the UIView as clickable?

I have already tried to override the `onTouchEnded` method, but when I added the labels and the images as sub-views to the view, the method is no longer called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when I added the labels and the images as subviews to the view the method is not called anymore.

Because UIImageView and UILabel have their `userInteractionEnabled` property set to `NO` by default. Set it to `YES` (true) and that should be fine.

Comment: thanks it worked.. another solution that worked for me was to override the draw function in the UIView and draw the labels and images manually. but i think that your solution is much better